# Carousel with images of different widths and different whitespace - how to achieve uniformity?

Tags: css, carousel, slick.js

I have a slick carousel that displays company logos. Some logos are rectangular, some are square. The slick carousel is set to show four logos at a time. Currently the square logos have white space around them so that their slide takes up 25% of the width of the carousel, but I want to eliminate that white space. I just can't wrap my head around how to do this while maintaining the responsive aspect of things.

You can see what I mean in the attached example image. How can I make it so that the desired result is achieved? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick carousel docs has info on this here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ just a little way down the page.

It gives this example of the carousel call but the `variableWidth` should be the kicker :

```
$('.variable-width').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. It looks like that will get me most of the way there. It's not perfect, as one logo will often be cut off when it is too wide for the parent div, but I can't think of any way to address that.